# how to solve "lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file."?

Tags: upgrade, magento-community, magento2.4.5, development, setup-upgrade

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires stripe/stripe-payments ^3.3.0, found stripe/stripe-payments[3.3.0] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires weltpixel/module-google-tag-manager ^1.10.18, found weltpixel/module-google-tag-manager[1.10.18] in the lock file but not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package to keep the one from the lock file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong 3rd-party modules.
As I already answered for you this is not Magento problem.
I think you need to remove this 2 extension, upgrade Magento to the necessary version and resolve current problem with these extensions.
Perhaps you have bad licences for these extensions. Then you need to check it and connect to vendor to upgrade